# Facebook error 210 "User not visible"

Tags: facebook

[php]

I've got an error "User not visible" with error code 210 as response while publishing content on friends wall via application.

:::Scenario is as follow:::

**User1** authorized my application with all the required permission ( including **publish_stream** and **offline_access** ) and now I am trying to post on **User1**'s friends wall...

At this time it gives me the error. I am using old rest API
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message,$attachment,$actionLink,$invV);

Help please!!!

Answer (score 5):

Your app may not have permission to post on the given friend's wall.

When a user authorizes your app, they give you permissions to act on their behalf.

This permission does not ensure that you can always post on friends' walls, just as the user may not be able to post on the wall using the UI.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error because I was using a Facebook Test User account when playing around with my app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do have "publish_stream" permissions, this occurs when you try to post to a wall, who is not friends w/ the user you are posting as.

Make sure there is a friends relationship between the two users, before posting to the others wall.

Answer (score 0):

It also appears when user is not allowing post on his wall( from Facebook setting).if is the case You should notify to user that "This user has privacy setting to himself only"

Comment: You can check that using FQL, querying the user.can_post attribute <- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue when having restricted usage of the Facebook app to a specific country. When trying to use the app from another country, I got an error.

*Country Restrictions* are available on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ > Settings > Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

> Facebook support has answered this question:
>
> `This error is returned when the posting user (A) does not have sufficient permission to post on User B's wall. This would be a privacy setting by user B and outside the control of User A or your app.`