# What are the causes of (#210) User not visible

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

1. Access token must be valid and contain publish_stream (checked, i do have valid access_token for the user who is posting to a friends wall
2. User A must be friends with user B (checked, posting user is friends with the one to whose wall he is about to post)
3. Posting use has app privacy settings set to "friends" (checked)
   ...?

I'm using Graph API (https://graph.facebook.com/{FRIEND_ID}/feed) for posting the message and i'm getting an (#210) User not visible OAuthException.

The stack about this problem here [Facebook error 210 "User not visible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214234/facebook-error-210-user-not-visible) has an anwser too general and thus doesn't allow me to debug / fix the problem anyhow.

I need to know what can be the causes for this error and how to fix em.
I've also filled a bug report out in the facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274389069292518 (just to see if there are anyone else having this issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook support has answered this question:

> This error is returned when the posting user (A) does not have
>   sufficient permission to post on User B's wall. This would be a
>   privacy setting by user B and outside the control of User A or your
>   app.

Comment: In the future, can you please provide a link to the source of information you quote? Thanks! For those wondering, it appears this came from a bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274389069292518/?browse=search_4f1014f69d0024b19184604

Comment: Why is a bug ? It's just a normal behavior according B user privacy isnit ?

Comment: Yes, it is a normal behavior which user A isn't in control of. But when developing I was not able to identify it as a privacy feature (Possibly because they didn't have a word about this use case in the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Never came across such an error but here are my ideas what causes it:

a) The user to whose Timeline (that's how the Wall is called now) you want to post to set the privacy setting "Who can post to my timeline" to "Only me"

b) The user to whose Timeline you want to post to has blocked the user you're trying to post as.