# Writing to a Facebook event wall raises "error #210: user is not visible" 

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a message to an event wall `https://graph.facebook.com/<EVENTID>/feed` with message parameter in the `POST`.

I have a valid access token from the user which has `publish_stream`, `friends_events`, `offline_access` permissions. I am getting this error consistently.

> {"error":{"message":"(#210) User not visible","type":"OAuthException","code":210}}

What am I missing?

Comment: Try using the Graph API explorer tool and see if you can replicate the issue.  Let us know.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce using the Graph API Explorer tool?

Comment: This was a facebook error probably due to their upgrade of "events" API. The same API works now (atleast for last 3-4 weeks)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I found the answer here: [What are the causes of (#210) User not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849813/what-are-the-causes-of-210-user-not-visible)

For me it was a matter of getting the right privacy settings/permissions for both users.